# Grab value from complex array and output as simple associative array

Tags: php

Please check attached images. These image contains `$complex_arr` print and `$simple_arr` print results. I want to convert  `$complex_arr` to `$simple_arr` output.

How is that possible? What is actually doing each of `$complex_arr` inside value will be converted as associative simple array like `$simple_arr`

```
$arr1 = array("asso1"=>"a", "asso2"=>"1");
$arr2 = array("asso1"=>"b", "asso2"=>"2");
$arr3 = array("asso1"=>"c", "asso2"=>"3");

$complex_arr = array($arr1,$arr2,$arr3);
$simple_arr = array("a"=>"1", "b"=>"2", "c"=>"3");

// print_r($complex_arr);
print_r($simple_arr);
```

**Input:**

[image: complex picture]

**Output:**

[image: simple picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write it on our own... here is my idea:

```
public function makeItSimpler($arr){
   $newarr = array();
   foreach($arr as $complex){
      $newarr[$complex['asso1']]=$complex['asso2'];
   }
   return $newarr;
}
```

Perhaps you can do it better... take look at "array-map" http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-map.php
Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($complex_arr as $key => $value) {
            $simple_arr[$value['asso1']]=$simple_arr[$value['asso2']];
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

With `php5.5` (where `array_column` becomes available) it is:

```
$simple_arr = array_combine(
    array_column($complex_arr, 'asso1'),
    array_column($complex_arr, 'asso2')
);
```

And even simplier (after I reread [function manual](http://php.net/array_column)):

```
$simple_arr = array_column($complex_arr, 'asso2', 'asso1');
```

Comment: Thanks, I've learnt a new method... Just one wee thing, the 2nd parameter shouldn't have the comma on the end as it makes the function call expect a missing and unwanted third parameter.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw thanks, edited.